# how to build fluent query by array of criterias in Laravel

Tags: laravel

If I store in DB criterias what I want to use to build and filter queries - how to build query with Laravel Fluent Query Builder? Maybe you can give advice for refactoring this array for adding OR/AND to make complex filter by such conditions? Thanks!

For example if I read from database these criteria and made array:

```
$array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'column' => 'name',
        'criteria' => 'LIKE'
        'value' => 'John'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'table' => 'groups',
        'column' => 'name',
        'criteria' => 'NOT LIKE'
        'value' => 'Administrator'
    ),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really set on doing it your way, make a switch statement to set the flag for the index of the array

```
switch ($query)
 {
 case 0:
   $this->get_data($x);
   break;
 case 1:
   $this->get_data($x);
   break;
 case 2:
   $this->get_data($x);
   break;
 default:
   Return FALSE;
 }
public function get_data($x){
$value = DB::table($array[$x]['table'])
->where($array[$x]['name'], $array[$x]['criteria'], $array[$x]['value'])
->get();

Return $value;
}
```

However, I would not advise this at all. Instead of storing the query filters in an array I feel you should just make them methods in your model. This will help with readability, modularity, and having reusable code.

```
public function get_user_by_name($name){
 $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
 return $user;
}

public function get_group_by_name($name, $criteria = 'LIKE'){
 $groups = DB::table('groups')->where('name', $criteria, '%'.$name.'%')->get();
 return $groups;
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent

Comment: Great! I need this, because user can choose models, columns, and record count for filtering.

Comment: I wouldn't put the get() inside the method but call it on the controller (or invoker). This way you keep an object to interact with (aka pagination, refined search, ...)